# Custom column names for DataGridView with associated DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource

How can I setup custom column names for DataGridView with associated DataSource?

Here is some code:

```
class Key
{
    public string Value { get; }
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; }
}

List<Key> keys = new List<Key>();
...// fill keys collection

DataGridView dataGridView = createAndInitializeDataGridView();
dataGridView.DataSource = keys;
```

This gives me dataGridView with column names "Value" and "ExpirationDate". How should I proceed to change names to "Key" and "Expire" for example?

Comment: If your data is coming from a database, you can change the column names in your SQL by aliasing them.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the [DisplayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute%28VS.90%29.aspx) attribute on your properties to specify column names in your DataGridView:

```
class Key
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Key")]
    public string Value { get; }
    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Expire")]
    public DateTime ExpirationDate { get; }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I am creating new objects based on this object, for example via Inner Joins.

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to change the header cells after you've set the datasource:

```
    if (dataGridView1.Columns["Value"] != null)
        dataGridView1.Columns["Value"].HeaderText = "Key";
    if (dataGridView1.Columns["Expiration"] != null)
        dataGridView1.Columns["Expiration"].HeaderText = "Expire";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. it worked, but Jay Riggs gave another answer that I like more.

Comment: Cool, yeh, I like his more as well, that goes in the memory bank :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public DataTable SetColumnsHeaderName(string[] TagName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    foreach (var item in TagName)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(item);
    }
    return dt;
}

public void ShowDataGridView()
{
    string[] tag = new string[] { "First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", };
    //fill datatable columns Name
    var dt = SetColumnsHeaderName(tag);
    //connect db and fetch table name
    var listx = db.tablename.ToList();
    foreach (var item in listx)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.Name, item.Family, item.Phone });
    }
    datagridView.DataSource = dt;
}
```