# If Statement inside LINQ Select Query

Tags: linq, if-statement, select

I has a table call Staff and has two field call StaffStatus and ParentStatus. I would like to display the Status as "Available" when StaffStatus AND ParentStatus are both "Available" and display the Status as "Unavailable" when either StaffStaus OR ParentStatus is "Unavailable".

```
Friend Function getAllUser(strInput As String) As IQueryable
getAllUser = From userDB In db.Staffs                    
             Select Status = userDB.UserStatus.Equals("Available") And userDB.ParentStatus.Equals("Available") ? "Available"  : (userDB.UserStatus.Equals("Unavailable") Or userDB.ParentStatus.Equals("Unavailable") ? "Unavailable")
End Function
```

But the code editor show : The character "?" cannot be used here and the Syntax error of first "(" at ": (userDB.UserStatus.Equals("Unavailable")". Any error with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: There is no ternary operator (as you use it) in VB.NET 
Take a look at here: [Is there a conditional ternary operator in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576431/is-there-a-conditional-ternary-operator-in-vb-net)

You have to use a `Dim foo as String = If(bar = uz, cat, dog)` construct

Edit: 
Try this

```
Dim getAllUser = From userDb In db.Staffs
                 Select New Staff() With
                     {
                     .UserStatus = If(userDb.UserStatus.Equals("Available") And userDb.ParentStatus.Equals("Available"), "Available", If(userDb.UserStatus.Equals("Unavailable") Or userDb.ParentStatus.Equals("Unavailable"), "Unavailable", "SomeOtherValue"))
                     }
```

Comment: but i wanna return it as IQueryable. This will return the type Staff?

Comment: you have 2 options: first would be to pack this in your function (I just wrote it this way since this is more natural for me than your old VBA/VBS style where you assign the value of the expression to your function) or second: simply add a **.AsQueryable()** at the end of the linq2sql command (don't forget to wrapt the expression in brackets)

Comment: How about if i wanna make it a name, like .UserStatus As Status? What command should i write? Just like the .UserStatus show as title Status.

Comment: don't get what you mean? do you want to create a extension methode or just add a further condition

Comment: sorry to confuse u. I want to display the result using the linq select statement in the dataGridView. I input the result using the code. `dgvUser.DataSource = helperUserCKJ.getAllUser(objUser.UserID)` Then for the query i would like to select all related column with a well display title. For example the column .UserStatus i want to display it with the a column name "Status".

Comment: The code i originally use is `        getAllUser = From userDB In db.Staffs
                     Order By userDB.UserStatus, userDB.Organization.OrganizationName, userDB.Company.CompanyName, userDB.Department.DepartmentName, userDB.Role.RoleName Descending, userDB.UserID
                     Where userDB.UserID IsNot strInput`

Comment: `        Select ID = userDB.UserID, Name = userDB.UserName, Gender = userDB.UserGender, Address = userDB.UserAddress1 & ", " & userDB.UserAddress2, State = userDB.UserState, Role = userDB.Role.RoleName, Organization = userDB.Organization.OrganizationName, Company = userDB.Company.CompanyName, Department = userDB.Department.DepartmentName, Status = userDB.UserStatus`

Comment: But now i wanna add the condition i mentioned before. I dun know how to write the linq statement...

Comment: to customize your datagrid colums, simply use the DisplayName Attribute (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6228673/6635287)