# What is preventing my List data from displaying in my DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net-core, datagridview

I was getting my list data into my DataGridView by simply populating a List<> and then assigning the List to the DataGridView's DataSource property, but after changing the column headings to be something other than the names of the class members which comprise the List, the assignation no longer works.

At least, no data displays in the grid.

The "funny" thing is that it still inserts the proper amount of rows (albeit empty) in the grid:

[image]

There are 14 "fake" (placeholder) rows that I am putting in the grid at the start. I don't know why changing the text in the column headings throws a spanner into the works.

The only changes I made from when it was working (but had ugly column heading titles) and now is this:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
```

-and the addition of the new columns:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MovieTitle", "Title");

. . .

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    LoadInitialData();
}

private void LoadInitialData()
{
    List<MoviesSingleTable> listStartupData = new List<MoviesSingleTable>();
    MoviesSingleTable mgdc;
    //1
    mgdc = new MoviesSingleTable
    {
    MovieTitle = "The Princess Bride",
    IMDBRating = 8.1,
    MPAARating = "PG",
    durationInMinutes = 98,
    YearReleased = "1987",
    genres = "", // will add these later
    actors = "",
    directors = "",
    screenwriters = ""
    };
    listStartupData.Add(mgdc);

    . . .

    //14
    mgdc = new MoviesSingleTable();
    mgdc.MovieTitle = "Will Penny";
    mgdc.IMDBRating = 7.1;
    mgdc.MPAARating = "NR"; // "Approved"
    mgdc.durationInMinutes = 108;
    mgdc.YearReleased = "1967";
    mgdc.genres = "";
    mgdc.actors = "";
    mgdc.directors = "";
    mgdc.screenwriters = "";
    listStartupData.Add(mgdc);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = listStartupData;
    ConfigureGrid(); 
}

private void ConfigureGrid()
{
    dataGridView1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MovieTitle", "Title");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("IMDBRating", "IMDB");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("MPAARating", "MPAA");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("durationInMinutes", "Minutes");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("YearReleased", "Year");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("genres", "Genres");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("actors", "Actors");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("directors", "Directors");
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("screenwriters", "Screenwriters");
}
```

The class used is:

```
public class MoviesSingleTable
{
    public string MovieTitle { get; set; }
    public double IMDBRating { get; set; }
    public string MPAARating { get; set; }
    public int durationInMinutes { get; set; }
    public string YearReleased { get; set; }
    public string genres { get; set; }
    public string actors { get; set; }
    public string directors { get; set; }
    public string screenwriters { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use [DisplayName] attribute on properties of class.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228199/custom-column-names-for-datagridview-with-associated-datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding the columns to the grid with code it will be necessary to set each column’s `DataPropertyName` to mate with the Class property name you want to display in that column.

Below is a helper method to return a column that sets the columns `DataPropertyName`.

```
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn GetColumnForGrid(string colName, string colHeader, string dataPropertyName) {
  DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgvc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
  dgvc.Name = colName;
  dgvc.HeaderText = colHeader;
  dgvc.DataPropertyName = dataPropertyName;
  return dgvc;
}
```

Also, I recommend you use a `BindingList<T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

Usage…

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  BindingList<MoviesSingleTable> data = GetData();
  DataGridViewColumn col = GetColumnForGrid("MovieTitle", "Title", "MovieTitle");
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
  col = GetColumnForGrid("IMDBRating", "IMDB", "IMDBRating");
  dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
  dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
  dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a champ; I don't know if BindingList is relatively new, but I don't recall every hearing of it before.

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon … It depends on what your requirements are. I am not an expert, however, the `BindingList` offers a little more functionality. I can’t think of all the different benefits, however one I am aware of is having the `DataGridView` display an empty “new” row at the end of the grid, which allows the user to add new rows.

Comment: Using the current `MoviesSingleTable` class as an example, if you use a `List<MoviesSingleTable>` you will NOT see this new row. If you use a `BindingList<MoviesSingleTable>`, then the user WILL be able to add new items to the list by directly adding rows to the grid. Again, this would certainly depend on your requirements.